# How to fetch keywords of a specific language into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, session

**Intro:** I used `session_start();` and set the session variable, `$_SESSION["lang"]=1` for English (default language) and `$_SESSION["lang"]=2` for Vietnamese. I retrieved keywords for the website as you can see from here **[hitechers.com](http://hitechers.com)** (I fetch the keywords from the so-called `words` table for each `lang_id` from the database, using `SELECT * FROM words WHERE lang_id = {$_SESSION['lang']}`.

**Question:** how can I get the keywords from the table in the user's language selection for the javascript's alerts or possible error messages (which is either English or Vietnamese) in the very much same way as the php scripts do for me, please?

Note:

- I have searched for other questions from here, and found that they suggest me use ajax as the **bridge** to pass values from server-side and client-side scripts, but no details have been given at all (!).
- I don't mean to echo the session variables, but just fetch the keywords associated with the lang_id 1 or 2 stored in the `$_SESSION` into the `Javascript`'s possible alerts or error messages only.

This is my words table query for your info:

```
$query = 'CREATE TABLE words (
    word_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lang_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    foo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    bar VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (word_id),
    UNIQUE (lang_id) ) ENGINE = MYISAM';`
```

Comment: FWIW, use the official locale abbreviations `'en'` for English and `'vi'` for Vietnamese, or any other non-numeric word that makes sense. Don't use magic numbers. You'll confuse the heck out of everyone including yourself eventually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have formatted the code as per SO standard - indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also added `sql` as the tag - so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely get what your problem is. What exactly do you mean by keywords and what should that website show off?

There are two ways you could get the data into your javascript: Either you prebuild a table of said keywords while delivering the language version or you use AJAX request to request the specified words. For the latter you'd have to have some kind of API/Interface available for retrieval.

As an example you could have a script called `retrieveword.php` that uses a get parameter to retrieve a single word. You already do have the language setup in the session so there shouldn't be a reason to include it in the call but of course you could do that as well. So your final call could look like this: `retrieveword.php?lang=1&word=5` and would deliver a simple JSON response like `{"foo": "something", "bar": "something", "wordid": 5, "langid": 1}`.

Alternatively you could bake that word list into your javascript as JSON as it is being delivered but depending on the size of your table that might be very wasteful and expose a lot of information.

Comment: "foo", is called a keyword, and "bar" is also called a keyword in the `words` table, of which the `lang_id` is the foreign key to link to the `languages` table. If the user selects Vietnamese (the lang_id is equal to # 2), then the "foo" keyword's value will return in Vietnamese or vice versa. Particularly speaking about my project - my website - you can see that the keyword `login` was translated to be `'Đăng nhập'` or `'register'` to be `'đăng ký'` if you switch the language to Vietnamese.

Comment: That data structure seems kind of strange except if you're doing actual translations. How are you referencing say the `"register"` string in the code? Do you look it up by the string or by the id? How do you generate the messages for the alerts/errors?